# Dynamic fields in SharePoint 2013 forms

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, jquery

I have a custom SharePoint list form where I would like to have country names(from another list) in one row with a check box in front of each row. On checking of any check box in front of country name, a text box should be enabled for each country where user can write the city name. I can get the country name using rest api and get the array of countries. Now how to implement the check box and city functionality?? Dynamically I need to have check box and a td where this text box should appear for number of countries called. Please advice...sharepoint 2013 client side javascripts/ jquery.

Table
Country name1 □  ______ 
Country name2 ■  Sydney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the checkbox in front of the country Name you can do like this:

You can either use REST or SPServices for this, I have done this using SPServices,

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Country List",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    if(Status == 'success' )
    {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
        {
            var value= $(this).attr("ows_ID");
            var text = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
            CountryArray.push({
                            title: text,
                            id: value
                        });
             $("BoxIDToAppendControl").append ( "<input id='chk_" + value + "' type='checkbox' value='" + value + "' onchange='GenerateTextBox()'/><label for='chk_" + value + "'>" +Conuntry Name + "</label>" );           

        });
    }
  }
});
```

Now In GenerateTextBox function you can write the following code

```
$(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
                            'value="Text Element ' + iCnt + '" />');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No SPServices. SP Services is not recommended for our project.

Comment: I said you can use REST api as well, I used SPService in my solution, you can use whatever you want and fill that country array accordingly, or else can directly traverse the data[] array of REST results

Comment: Did your question got solved?

Comment: Yeah did it...It was nt that difficult as I thought of..binder the html using rest services...It worked